# Как поменять цвет текста в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть ListView сщ значениями заполненное с помощю SimpleCursorAdapter, мне нужно чтобы при минусовых значение цвет текста менялся на красный.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше создайте свой адаптер унаследованный от BaseAdapter со списком необходимых значений, и в getView проверяйте Ваши данные и меняйте TextView по необходимому условию